# Ум и эрудированность

Tags: семантика

**Может ли умный человек не быть при этом эрудированным?**

Задумался о семантических отличиях *ума, мудрости* и *эрудиции*. Мудрый человек обязательно умный, но не обязательно эрудированный, а вот взрослый человек умный, может ли при этом быть неэрудированным?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Можно ли считать эрудированным человека, который знает все тонкости стилей, допустим, художников Возрождения, импрессионистов там всяких, но не может отличить Бёрнса от Киплинга?

Т.е. "эрудированный" - это обязательно во всех (во многих) областях, или достаточно одной узкой сферы?

Comment: На вопрос невозможно ответить, не зная, что вы понимаете под "эрудированным". Чем эрудированный человек отличается от неэрудированного? Где вы проводите границу?

Comment: @stopkran, мне интересно, что думают о значении этих слов другие, даже если их понимание эрудиции и ума отличается от моего. Поэтому ограничивать кого-либо своими определениями я не хочу.

Comment: Но тогда, простите, схема вашего вопроса выглядит как "Выскажите мнения об отношениях между А, Б и В. И заодно дайте А, Б и В определения". 

Это минимум 6 разных вопросов. И очень непростых.

Comment: @stopkran, вы предлагаете в стиле Галактиона разбить вопрос на 6 частей?

Меня интересует только соотношение между умом и эрудицией, я понимаю, что для ответа человеку нужно знать значение этих слов, но не вижу смысл разделять из-за этого вопрос.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь: _только ум и эрудиция_ или _ещё и мудрость_. Или ваше утверждение "мудрый человек обязательно умный" мы должны принять как бесспорное?

Comment: @stopkran, меня интересует только ум и эрудированность, если вы не согласны с тем, что мудрый человек необязательно эрудированный, можете оспорить это или не оспаривать, на моё мнение об ответе это не повлияет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ответе на мои комментарии вы даёте широкий простор толкованиям. Вроде как можно отвечать на выбор, кому о чём нравится. Я выбираю следующий путь:

1. Сузим вопрос, отбросив ваши реверансы в сторону Бегемотуса ("Шура, вы знаете, как я уважаю Остапа Ибрагимовича, но...") и вернув ему (вопросу) первоначальный вид.
2. Ограничим один из терминов так, чтобы появилась возможность ответа.

В итоге получится что-то вроде "Может ли умный взрослый человек не быть эрудированным хотя бы в одной узкой области?"

И на такой вопрос я с уверенностью отвечу: нет.

Comment: Уточнение: в _моём_ понимании **умный** - это тот, о ком коллеги (товарищи, соседи...) время от времени говорят: "Ну нифига себе, какой ты умный!"

**Эрудированный** - тот, кому коллеги (товарщи, соседи...) чаще других задают вопросы и, как правило, получают полезные ответы.

Comment: Уточнение по поводу эрудиции. Вопросы типа *Стоит ли мне встречаться с данным человеком?*, относятся в вашем понимании к эрудиции или нет?

Comment: Иногда в ответе на такой вопрос эрудиция бывает необходима (например, _созависимые_ люди знают массу неочевидных признаков наркоманов). 

Иногда эрудиция тут бесполезна, а гораздо важнее другое качество - _интуиция_ (_шестое чувство_ или "врождённая грамотность", как тут где-то говорили).

Answer (score 4):

Да запросто. 
Эрудированность ни из ума, ни из мудрости не вытекает. И наоборот, кстати, тоже. 
Эрудированность - это знания, а ум и даже мудрость - вообще говоря знаний не требует.
У всяких там горцев (и не только) всех стариков считают мудрыми - и в известном смысле не без оснований. А какая у них эрудиция? Горы да бараны - вот все их науки.

Тут скорее надо разбирать, должен ли умный быть мудрым - или наоборот. 
По мне так это тоже вещи пересекающиеся лишь частично. Можно быть и мудрым, но не умным, и наоборот. 
Вот, кстати. "Предками данная мудрость народная" - это что про ***умных*** людей сказано? Извините, но это про каких-то марионеток на веревочках, у коих своего ни ума, ни сообразительности...

Вообще, помнится, в философии есть понятие разума, объединяющее все упомянутые качества (включая сообразительность). А есть разумность. Вот она-то ума не требует. Но вполне, имхо, может возрасти до мудрости, минуя даже собственно ум, который разум.

Comment: Ну, вы наворотили! :-) Ум - это, скажем, "вычислительная способность", возможность быстро всё "просчитать" и ответить на вопрос. Но если отвечающий не знает слов (обозначающих исходные посылки и варианты возможных ответов), он не сможет ответить.

Ум, оперирующий "ничем", никак нельзя измерить (сказать, умный человек, или нет). Таким образом, какой-то минимум знаний (эрудиции) просто необходим для проявления ума.

Comment: >Ум - это, скажем, "вычислительная способность",  
  
Брррр... И кто из нас "наворотил" после этого? Вычислительная способность - это ***рассудочность***. Присущая, кстати, даже многим высшим животным.

Comment: хорошо, оставим существительные, вопрос был не о них. Какого человека можно назвать _умным_? По каким действиям (проявлениям) мы можем отличить его от человека _не очень умного_?

Answer (score 3):

Ум и эрудированность - разные вещи, причем, одно совершенно не означает другое. Например, я себя считаю эрудированным человеком, но отнюдь не считаю умным. Эрудиция - это некий багаж знаний, своего рода википедия нашей памяти. А ум - это умение оценивать обстановку, делать правильные выводы и находить выходы из разных ситуаций. И, кстати, ум - это еще и умение пользоваться своей эрудицией.
А эрудиция без ума - это Сатин, который знал много умных слов, но понятия не имел, как ими пользоваться.))))

Answer (score 1):

Мы общаемся на языке общения. А мыслим на языке мышления. Излишняя загруженность эрудированностью (знаниями на языке общения) может сбить подсознательные процессы, обеспечивающие мышленте.

Comment: В общем-то согласен, но как эти рассуждения соотносятся с вопросом?

Answer (score -3):

1. Я почти ничего не знаю и почти ничего не умею.
2. Я знаю, что существуют разные формы интеллекта, включая тупоумие и хитроумие.
3. Я с интересом наблюдаю за тем, как Марк Из демонстрирует хитроумие (например, в предложении "А южноамериканский - не южный и американский.").

Comment: 1. Умный - тот, кто может понять Галактиона.
2. Эрудированный - тот, кто может ответить на его вопросы. 
3. Мудрый - тот, кто эти вопросы перестал открывать.
:)))

Comment: Dear Элен.

Не огорчайтесь, пожалуйста.

Прощайте.